# How to get Confusion matrices for each classification in Weka Experiment (API)

Tags: java, weka

I am trying to use Weka experimenter via code provided here:https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/files/ExperimentDemo.java. This actually gives you the TP; FP rates etc. But is there a way to get confusion matrix for each classification ? For example which classes were classified as which ones ?

Answer (score 0):

No, Weka's Experiment API does not store the confusion matrix. You can see for yourself in the source code by inspecting the responsible class: `weka.experiment.ClassifierSplitEvaluator`.

However, you can store targets and predictions in the results (`ClassifierSplitEvaluator.setPredTargetColumn(boolean)`) and then you could compute the confusion matrices yourself.